# mysql table with duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
email(email varchar(30),id integer(10),duplicated varchar(10))
```

with records

```
    sai@gmail.com      101   null  
    kiran@gmail.com    102   null  
    sai123@gmail.com   103   null  
    sai@gmail.com      101   null  
    kiran@gmail.com    102   null
```

Now my question is i need to get "yes" in the duplicated column for the two duplicated records for the second time. so, the output table should be

```
    sai@gmail.com      101   null  
    kiran@gmail.com    102   null  
    sai123@gmail.com   103   null  
    sai@gmail.com      101   yes  
    kiran@gmail.com    102   yes
```

Comment: you will not get this output as there is no unique present. output will be yes for all sai@gmail.com and kiran@gmail.com .i.e. top 2 and last 2 record will update to duplicate yes

Comment: You have two "sai@gmail.com" rows in your example. How can SQL distinguish them, so that the first gets NULL, and the second gets "duplicated"? You need to supply a criterion (e.g. add a unique ID to each row, and select the lower). Or do you just want to deduplicate the table?

Comment: You can do that when you are inserting the data then check that this value is present then make it as yes else null

Comment: Are there no other columns? And why call it "id" when it's not?

Comment: kk thanq so much for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update email set duplicated =
    (case when (select count(*) from email x where x.email = e.email) > 1 then "yes" else null)
```

edited: this will update table

Comment: this will get both the records as yes but i should get only the second time repeated record as duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query for viewing:

```
select numerated.email, numerated.id, (case when cnt=1 OR numerated.rnum=grouped.min_rnum then null else "yes" end) as duplicated
from 
    (select @i := @i + 1 as rnum, email.* from email, (select @i:=0) as c order by id) as numerated
left join 
    (select email, id, min(rnum) as min_rnum, count(rnum) as cnt 
        from (select @i := @i + 1 as rnum, email.* from email, (select @i:=0) as c order by id) as numerated 
        group by email, id
    ) as grouped
on numerated.email=grouped.email and numerated.id=grouped.id
order by id;
```

Could you explain your situation in details? It looks like it needs another solution, not just SELECT query.

And try this one for updating:

```
update email u, (select @i:=0) urnum
set
  id = id + (@i:=@i + 1) - @i,
  duplicated = (
    select duplicated from (
        select 
            numerated.email, 
            numerated.id, 
            (case when cnt=1 OR numerated.rnum=grouped.min_rnum then null else "yes" end) as duplicated, 
            rnum
        from
            (select @i := @i + 1 as rnum, email.* from email, (select @i:=0) as c ) as numerated
        left join
            (select email, id, min(rnum) as min_rnum, count(rnum) as cnt
                from (select @i := @i + 1 as rnum, email.* from email, (select @i:=0) as c ) as numerated
                group by email, id
            ) as grouped
        on numerated.email=grouped.email and numerated.id=grouped.id
        order by rnum
    ) found_duplicates
    where u.email=found_duplicates.email and u.id=found_duplicates.id and @i=found_duplicates.rnum
    limit 1
  )
;
```

It looks like it works, but you shouldn't rely on it.

If it is possible, you should do any of this:
1. change table structure - add unique field
2. change table filling logic - check uniqueness before inserting new row and insert it with proper 'duplicates' field value;
3. repopulate via temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_email AS <... 'SELECT' version of my query ...>;  
TRUNCATE TABLE email;  
INSERT INTO email SELECT * FROM tmp_email;
```

Comment: But,it is just displaying, it is not updating the table.

Comment: @saikiran Sorry, I missed that you needed it. Made a huge update to my answer.